# Paypal shipping amount not taken during checkout

Tags: php, paypal

While making payment,the paypal doesn't include the shipping amount. Its only taking the amount 15. Its not taking the amount 22
There are the values that pass to the paypal:

METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=78.0&PWD=FGZCWYGDRMDTP&USER=supp&SIGNATURE=bYYmK0aHbiCnrA.5R4-Jpk8Aa8&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=22&RETURNURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com.au%2Fcart%2Fexpresscheckout%2ForderID%2FiGtRlKT2u4f8.%2F&CANCELURL=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test.com.au%2Fcart%2FunholdCart%2ForderID%2FiGtRlKT2u4f8.%2F&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=AUD&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=15&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=0&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_SHIPPINGAMT=7&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ALLOWNOTE=1&PAGESTYLE=Tral faory&LOGOIMG=http://www.test/public/uploads/settings/company_logo_paypal.gif&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Lightweight Packing Cubes:Only $15 for a set of Three Bright and Colourful. Perfect for Organising your Suitcase.&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=Lightweight Packing Cubes:Only $15 for a set of Three Bright and Colourful. Perfect for Organising y&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=15&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1

please see the image after entering into payment site:
[image: paypal image]

Comment: I'm confused.  The screenshot you're showing does show the shipping..??

Comment: yes its showing the shipping amount.but din't include that while payment..Any Solution?

Answer (score 0):

The final call, DoExpressCheckoutPayment, is the end-all-be-all.  If you don't include the same shipping, item details, etc. in DECP as you do in SEC then it won't get included in the final payment.